# Does Bash Have a Thread Yield?

Tags: multithreading, bash

A thread yield signifies to the OS that the process is not expecting to need the CPU for a while, and that the scheduler should preemptively switch to another process.  For example, in C++11, the call is `std::this_thread::yield()`.

**Does Bash have such a command?  If so, what is it?**

Comment: There is nothing similar in Bash that I"ve seen in the better part of 20 years.  All calls to 3rd party apps will invoke an additional subshell, except possibly calling read to read from a file (or pipe or stdin), and then writing data to the pipe when you are ready to continue.

Comment: Bash doesn't have threading at all, so a threading-specific call such as the C++ "alternative" given isn't exactly like-for-like. In general, bash code that's reasonably written will be spending its time blocking (waiting either on IO for subprocesses to exit), either of which yields the CPU implicitly.

Comment: Yielding is not about advising the system about process / thread expectations.  The OS doesn't need any such thing, because it can *see* what the process *actually* needs at any given time.  Yielding is about one thread proactively giving other threads a chance to run even though that thread *does* have more work to perform.  And no, `bash` has no such thing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you have a good source for it not existing, that sounds like an answer. Negative-result answers are fine here too, since I am concerned about knowing whether it exists at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yielding is not about advising the system about process / thread expectations. The OS doesn't need such help, because it can see what the process actually does need at any given time.  On the contrary, yielding is about one thread proactively giving others a chance to run even though that thread *does* have more work to perform.   Schedulers are pretty good at divvying up CPU resources even without such help.

In any case, no, `bash` has no such thing, as you can check by reading the manual's [list of internal commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Commands) and its [list of built-ins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands).

People do seem to get confused, however, between `bash` itself (or any other shell) and *external* commands that it can run for you.  External commands are in no way part of the shell, but some are standbys of shell programming (`grep`, `awk`, and `sed` being the first that come to mind).  Any program you can obtain or write, however, you can run via `bash`.  In particular, you can build this C program for the job:

```
#include <sched.h>
int main() {
    sched_yield();
    return 0;
}
```

If you launch that from a shell then it will indeed yield the CPU while the parent shell is waiting for it to finish.  The shell itself will not yield, but since it will be blocked on the child's completion, the effect will still be to proactively allow other processes to run.  But what incredible overhead that involves!

In the end, @CharlesDuffy's comment laid out the situation very succinctly:

> bash code that's reasonably written will be spending its time blocking (waiting either on IO [or] for subprocesses to exit), either of which yields the CPU implicitly.

If your `bash` script seems to have a genuine use for an explicit `yield` then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the negative result. Knowing what's not possible is just as important as knowing what is. FWIW, this came up in the accepted answer on [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/627019/blocking-start-of-terminal).

Comment: Good answer overall, however, the last link about if you need a yield, then you are doing something wrong is a really bad mindset. There are many reasons outside of IO blocking that may have the use for yeild. A example (not the only one) may be to processes large data with a small amount of memory, and writing with a yeild, may be the most elegant solution.

Comment: @Jdahern, the last comment is not about yielding *in general*, it is about "*If your `bash ` script ...*" seems to have a need to yield.  In the example you present, to the extent that it applies, at least one thing you would be doing wrong would be using the shell itself (as opposed to a program it launches) to do any significant amount of data processing.

Answer (score 0):

In bash (or any program really) you can yield by calling `sleep 0`. In most cases this will invoke the kernel's scheduler to reevaluate which process should be run next. In some common extended versions, you can even call `sleep` with a floating point number for a regular subsecond sleep time.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Since `sleep` isn't a bash built-in, this will require creating a process and destroying a process. That's hardly the kind of load you want to impose when your whole goal is to be nice to other things that want to get work done.

Comment: Nearly everything in bash requires this. It's fine. Sleep will "sleep" in the system call while other processes are running.

Comment: @Misandrist, but with `0`, it's exiting immediately, so the expense of spawning the sleep executable is far, *far* higher than anything saved. The OP is presumably trying to figure out how to be a well-behaved citizen, and putting `sleep 0` in one's polling loops isn't it. (Avoiding polling loops in the first place, on the other hand...)

Comment: Also yield returns immediately if there's nothing else asking to run. sleep() is the process system call to use for this.

Comment: Sure you have other options. Read from a FIFO that doesn't have anything writing to it, to pull one out. :)

Comment: That blocks, and if you're trying to deschedule your process, that just blocks it and won't let it continue until something is written.